# How to synchronously execute an Lwt thread

Tags: ocaml, synchronous, ocaml-lwt

Is there any way to synchronously execute a thread made with Lwt library?

To be specific, I am trying to run a series of post requests to a server that compute some value and returns a result.

Based on answers provided to this question:

[How do I make a simple GET request in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070455/how-do-i-make-a-simple-get-request-in-ocaml)

I can make it with either low level approach (sockets) or using the Cohttp library.
The low level approach has the advantage of being immediate and straightforward but I would rather stick to the Cohttp (no need for read/write loop etc.). Unfortunately I am completely new to the Lwt and based on:
https://mirage.io/wiki/tutorial-lwt
I understand that the only way to get result from `a t` to `a` is to run `Lwt_main.run` which is suppose to be invoked at top level which is not an option for me.

TL:DR

Is there any way get a result from:

`Client.get (Uri.of_string "http://localhost:8080/res")`

without calling `Lwt_main.run` or is calling `Lwt_main.run` for each request (deep inside a code) not so bad idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Lwt_main.run` deep inside the program, provided the call is not nested inside an outer call to `Lwt_main.run`. It sounds like it won't be nested in your case, so you can call it where you make the request.