# OCaml - Parmap executing Lwt threads hangs on the execution

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt

This is a follow up to this question:
[How to synchronously execute an Lwt thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797475/how-to-synchronously-execute-an-lwt-thread)

I am trying to run the following piece of code:

```
open Lwt
open Cohttp_lwt_unix

let server_content2 x  =
    "in server content x" |> print_endline ;
    Client.get (Uri.of_string ("http://localhost:8080/"^x)) >>= fun (_, body) ->
        (Cohttp_lwt.Body.to_string body) >|= fun sc -> sc
        ;;
let reyolo () =
    List.init 10 (fun i -> server_content2 (string_of_int i) ) ;;
let par () = 
    let yolo = reyolo () in
    "in par" |> print_endline;
    Parmap.pariter 
        ~ncores:4 
        (fun p ->  "before run" |> print_endline ; "content:"^(Lwt_main.run p) |> print_endline  ; "after run" |> print_endline ) 
        (Parmap.L yolo);;

par ()
```

I expected this to perform 10 remote connections.
What I get is in *par* function `Lwt_main.run` seems to stuck before doing an actual remote call.

I doubt it might be of any significance but the server that suppose to respond is made in python and looks like this:

```
import subprocess
from bottle import run, post, request, response, get, route

@route('/<path>',method = 'GET')
def process(path):
    print(path)
    return "yolo"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: I can respond to a simpler example; I highly doubt this is minimal. Among other changes, are you able to remove usage of Parmap, replacing it with, perhaps, Unix.fork? Or nothing at all?

Comment: I slimmed down the example. About the second part, Parmap is the key element of this problem because I want to integrate remote connections to my existing program that already uses Parmap. Getting rid of Parmap would end up in much more work than finding/implementing other solutions for remote get/post (with sockets for example).

Comment: What I would do here, is inline the [source code](https://github.com/rdicosmo/parmap/blob/master/src/parmap.ml) of Parmap by creating several local modules in my program, and copying the source of Parmap into them. I would then slim down the resulting combined program, until hopefully only the call to `fork` was left. I would also try to reduce the 10-element list to 2 or even 1. It's less to worry about, and if you look at Parmap, it behaves differently if the number of cores is less than the fan-out, and that's useful to eliminate, if it is not necessary.

Comment: Alternatively, someone freely familiar with Parmap may be able to answer this outright, but I would have to defer to such a person :)

Comment: However, I do see that all your calls to `server_content2` occur in the parent process. What if you stored functions in `yolo`, or arguments (`string_of_int i` or `i`), so that `server_content2` would only get called in each child process?

Comment: I think you are on the right track, if I move initialization of a remote call inside `Parmap.pariter` then some of the calls are getting through. I say some because it sometimes does not work. For example if I change the length of the `yolo` list to 100 then sometimes 4 calls are established, sometimes 70+ and sometimes all of them.

Comment: @antron after some more tests I came to a conclusion that the second reason for hanging up of threads was due to the server misbehavior. Right now I am using JSON-RPC server made in c++ and nothing like this happens. So the answer for the original question that you provided was a correct one. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the calls to `server_content2`, which start the requests, occur in the parent process. The code then tries to finish them in the child processes spawned by `Parmap`. Lwt breaks here: it cannot, in general, keep track of I/Os across a `fork`.

If you store either thunks or arguments in the list `yolo`, and delay the calls to `server_content2` so that they are done in the child processes, the requests should work. To do that, make sure the calls happen in the callback of `Parmap.pariter`.